# spring converter not registering

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-data-rest 
and trying to send PATCH request to the server with data as a long

so there patch

```
[{"op":"replace","path":"/serviceDate","value":1262304000000}]
```

on the server side i expect long to be converted to java.util.date, but instead of it i get

> ConverterNotFoundExcepion No converter found capable of converting
>   from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.util.Date]

i tried to register custom converter like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

    registry.addConverter(new LongToDateConverter());
  }
}
```

and even like this

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterServiceConfiguration {
@Bean(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    HashSet<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
    converters.add(new LongToDateConverter());
    bean.setConverters(converters);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    ConversionService object = bean.getObject();
    return object;
   }
}
```

but nothing happend. 
I also saw in debugger, that for converting id from request(from string to Long) spring use DefaultFormattingConvertionService(which have capable converters), but for converting value spring use DefaultConversionService, and this class really dont have needed converter, that i have registered. 
How can i add my converter, so spring can convert it?

Here stacktrace

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler - Could not read an object of type class com.mapp.database.entity.Customer from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1034E:(pos 0): A problem occurred whilst attempting to set the property 'serviceDate': Type conversion failure
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read an object of type class com.mapp.database.entity.Customer from the request!; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1034E:(pos 0): A problem occurred whilst attempting to set the property 'serviceDate': Type conversion failure
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPatch(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.mcompany.filter.CORSFilter.doFilterInternal(CORSFilter.java:29)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1034E:(pos 0): A problem occurred whilst attempting to set the property 'serviceDate': Type conversion failure
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.writeProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:262)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.setValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:159)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.setValue(SpelExpression.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.patch.PatchOperation.setValueOnTarget(PatchOperation.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.patch.ReplaceOperation.perform(ReplaceOperation.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.patch.Patch.apply(Patch.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.JsonPatchHandler.applyPatch(JsonPatchHandler.java:89)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.JsonPatchHandler.apply(JsonPatchHandler.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.readPatch(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:198)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Type conversion failure
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor.write(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.writeProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:255)
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:(pos 0): Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.lang.Long to java.util.Date
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor.write(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:240)
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [java.util.Date]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeConverter.convertValue(StandardTypeConverter.java:74)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You are sending JSON that shouldn't be even using the converters.  Next to that you are using Spring boot. Instead of a snippet please add the full stack trace.

Comment: but it use( 
here, i have added it to the post

Comment: "on the server side i expect long to be converted to java.util.date" why do you expect that?

Comment: because it is like spring-data-rest functioning in other requests, in put/get/post or even merge-patch requests

Comment: Please show your controller. It doesn't make sense that the converter is used as you are posting JSON. JSON doesn't use binding but marshaling and marshaling doesn't use the converters.

Comment: Hi. But as you can see from stacktrace it is used, and as it spring-data-rest i dont have controllers. It is only have repositories, which is simple declaration of interface with repository annotation. I think it is because patch use another method(it is patch, not post), but i need to patch dates and i cant understand how

Comment: Did you find a solution so far?  I have a similar problem with String to LocalTime conversion.